# Is there a way to multiply inputs when they begin with a decimal like this- .125 or even 0.7854... My result winds up being 0 or NaN

Tags: javascript, html

I need some insight again. I am trying to multiply three inputs times two hidden numbers. Two inputs being the same number (since i have yet to figure out how to Square a input). The calculation i am after is a Force calc we use in O&G. Wire diameter * Wire Diameter * Well Head Pressure * .7854(variable)  * 1.5;; Eg. .125 * .125 * 6500 * .7854 * 1.5; Which should result in 119.65 (lbs)- instead i get NAN or if i use decimal like this 0.125 i get a result of 0. To Note the function works if i leave the decimal out all together but the answer is wrong naturally.

My Code

```
       <div class="containerForce">
            <p>
              <h1>Force Calculation - Weight Required to Fall</h1>
              <label>Wire OD</label>
              <input type="number" id="num05">
              <label>Wire OD</label>
              <input type="number" id="num06">
              <label>Well Head Pressure</label>
              <input type="number" id="num07">
            <p>
                <input type="button" id="btn01" style="background-color: rgb(104, 199, 206)"
                 value="Required Weight" onclick="cal()" />
            </p>
              <p id="total3"></p>
        </div>
```

Java Function

```
 function cal() {
    var numZero5 = document.getElementById('num05').value;
    var numZero6 = document.getElementById('num06').value;
    var numZero7 = document.getElementById('num07').value;
    var total3 = parseInt(numZero5) * parseInt(numZero6) * parseInt(numZero7) * .7854 * 1.5;
    var p = document.getElementById('total3');
    p.innerHTML += total3;
  }
```

Comment: your code works just fine, no `NaN` result no `0` result - as long as you enter integers (since you parseInt) ... did you mean `parseFloat` instead?

Comment: you may want to use `document.getElementById('num05').valueAsNumber` also, then you don't need to `parseFloat`

Comment: Your HTML is violently invalid.

Comment: @Rob - violently?

Comment: @JaromandaX Violently.

Comment: @Rob - thanks for the (not) clarification :p

Comment: Thank you all for the insight, on the html comment- i am sure this looks awful as i have just began learning to code two weeks ago lol. Many thanks Experts.

Comment: @JaromandaX It knocked me on the floor

Comment: @Rob - using an online html validator for the HTML did not even produce a warning - so, how is it invalid?

Comment: @JaromandaX This is one of those corner cases that works and I didn't catch it. A `<p>` element may not contain a `<h1>` but the way this is written, a closing `</p>` wasn't used and the first tag is closed automatically and you can find that rule in the specification. Therefore, in this case, it's valid. If he had closed the first `<p>` it would be flagged as invalid. Add a closing tag to the first `<p>` after the `<h1>` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Rob - I'll believe you :p

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are parsing your inputs to Integers. Integers are whole numbers, so everything after the decimal seperator is thrown away.
You can reproduce this behaviour by executing `parseInt(1.5)` in the browser console.

The method you are looking for is `parseFloat()` or `Number()`. I personally would go with `parseFloat()`.

Additionally, you might want to change your last line to `p.innerHTML = total3;` so you replace the result in the paragraph instead of concetinating your results.

```html
 <div class="containerForce">
   <h1>Force Calculation - Weight Required to Fall</h1>
   <label>Wire OD</label>
   <input type="number" id="num05">
   <label>Wire OD</label>
   <input type="number" id="num06">
   <label>Well Head Pressure</label>
   <input type="number" id="num07">
   <p>
     <input type="button" id="btn01" style="background-color: rgb(104, 199, 206)"
            value="Required Weight" onclick="cal()" />
   </p>
   <p id="total3"></p>
</div>     
<script> 
function cal() {
  var numZero5 = document.getElementById('num05').value;
  var numZero6 = document.getElementById('num06').value;
  var numZero7 = document.getElementById('num07').value;
  var total3 = parseFloat(numZero5) * parseFloat(numZero6) * parseFloat(numZero7) * .7854 * 1.5;
  var p = document.getElementById('total3');
  p.innerHTML = total3;
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you go with `type="number"` then why not `.valueAsNumber` instead of `.value`?